# java.lang.NullPointerException error while wrting data in copy of excel sheet

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, jxl

When I run the below code it give me "java.lang.NullPointerException" error. I m new in Selenium Data Driven testing and want to write my pass/fail results in copy of excel sheet. Please help me out and guide me in creating an excel sheet copy and write in that copy sheet. 
Currently it is creating Copy of excel sheet but when "wshTemp.addCell(labTemp);" get execute it give above error. Thank u in advance.

```
import java.io.File;
import jxl.Workbook;
import jxl.write.WritableSheet;
import jxl.write.WritableWorkbook;
import jxl.write.Label;
import jxl.write.WriteException;


public class dataSheet {

    static Workbook wbook;
    static WritableWorkbook wwbCopy;
    static String ExecutedTestCasesSheet;
    static WritableSheet shSheet;

    public void readExcel()
    {
    try{
    wbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File("path\\testSampleData.xls"));
    wwbCopy = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File("path\\testSampleDataCopy.xls"), wbook);
    shSheet = wwbCopy.getSheet(0);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }

    public void setValueIntoCell(String strSheetName,int iColumnNumber, int iRowNumber,String strData) throws WriteException
    {
        WritableSheet wshTemp = wwbCopy.getSheet(strSheetName);
        Label labTemp = new Label(iColumnNumber, iRowNumber, strData);

        try {
            wshTemp.addCell(labTemp);
             } 
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

    public void closeFile()
    {
        try {
            // Closing the writable work book
            wwbCopy.write();
            wwbCopy.close();

            // Closing the original work book
            wbook.close();
        } catch (Exception e)

        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws WriteException
    {
        dataSheet ds = new dataSheet();
        ds.readExcel();
        ds.setValueIntoCell("sheet1", 5, 1, "PASS");
        ds.setValueIntoCell("sheet1", 5, 2, "FAIL");
        ds.setValueIntoCell("sheet1", 5, 3, "PASS");
        ds.closeFile();
    }
}
```

Comment: check if wshTemp is null after creating it, maybe getSheet simply returns null instrad of a proper object

Comment: Hi, basically i am using POI for excel handling, any how in you code i am not able to fine code to create sheet.. not required to create sheet after creating workbook? which API you are using?

Comment: hii murali .. I m using java jxl API

Comment: hii friends got the solution of my problem ..... I just replace 'Sheet name' with 'Sheet number' like "WritableSheet wshTemp = wwbCopy.getSheet(strSheetName)" with "WritableSheet wshTemp = wwbCopy.getSheet(0);" and this code worked ...... thanks for your help !!!!!!